# string inside attribute comparison jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, comparison

I am trying to compare the content of the attributes of some elements like :

```
<video id="videoarea" src="content1"></video>
<span class="videoquality" someattr="content2">link1</span>
<span class="videoquality" someattr="content3">link2</span>
<span class="videoquality" someattr="content4">link3</span>
```

and add a .link class to the `<span>`s when the value of the `someattr` attribute is different from the video `src` value.

I am doing this in jquery :

```
<script>
var lecturl = $("#videoarea").attr("src") ;
$( ".videoquality[someattr!=$(lecturl)]" ).addClass("link");
</script>
```

But this does not work... I can't seem to find why. 
What am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that it will result in invalid HTML if you create your own attributes on elements. If you need to store custom data within an element use `data-*` instead.

Your actual issue is because string interpolation only works in Javascript when using template literals. To delimit a template literal, use backticks (``` `` ```) and then wrap the value in `${}`, like this:

```js
var lecturl = $("#videoarea").attr("src") ;
$(`.videoquality[data-someattr!="${lecturl}"]`).addClass("link");
```

```css
.link { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="videoarea" src="content1"></video>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content2">link1</span>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content3">link2</span>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content4">link3</span>
```

However you should be aware that template literals are completely unsupported in IE (without a polyfill). If you need IE support then the simplest way is to use traditional string concatenation:

```js
var lecturl = $("#videoarea").attr("src") ;
$('.videoquality[data-someattr!="' + lecturl + '"]').addClass("link");
```

```css
.link { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="videoarea" src="content1"></video>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content2">link1</span>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content3">link2</span>
<span class="videoquality" data-someattr="content4">link3</span>
```

Comment: As you can see from the snippets in the answer above, this should work fine. Check  the console for errors in your production version, and also ensure that the `.link` class is of high enough specificity to override existing styling rules.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all of the elements and check their attributes.

```
var lecturl = $("#videoarea").attr("src");
  for(i=0;i < $(span).length-1;i++){
   if($("span")[i].getAttribute("someattr") != lecturl){
    $("span")[i].addClass("link");
}
}
```